# Jquery each what is meant by the value after function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.each(objectName, function() {}, something)
```

In the above question what is meant by 'something' in jquery

Comment: Where are you getting this from? Jquery each only takes 2 paramaters, an object and a callback.

Comment: Read this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ you will get a fair idea about that. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) API-documentation from Jquery there is no such parameter. It is just kind of:

```
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {}
```